# How to send additional data to jQuery File Upload Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

This would seem stupid but i can't seem to understand the documentation.
I'm talking about [This](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) plugin for file upload.

Now according to the documentation there's an option :

> **formData**
>
> Additional form data to be sent along with the file uploads can be set using this
>    option, which accepts an array of objects with name and value properties, a function 
>    returning such an array, a FormData object (for XHR file uploads), or a simple object.
>    The form of the first fileInput is given as parameter to the function.
>
> **Note**: Additional form data is ignored when the multipart option is set to false.
>
> Type: Array, Object, function or FormData Default: A function
>   returning the form fields as serialized Array:
>
> ```
> function (form) {
>     return form.serializeArray();
> }
> ```
>
> **Example:**
>
> [
>       {
>           name: 'a',
>           value: 1
>       },
>       {
>           name: 'b',
>           value: 2
>       } ]

Which i fail to understand what i'm suppoused to do with that.

This is how i initialize the plugin :

```
$('#add_image_upload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
    sequentialUploads: true,
    formData : getDate
});
```

And this is my attempt to the function :

```
 function getDate(){

//if user didn't selected a date
if(!selectedDate || selectedDate=="undefined"){
selectedDate = "1/1/"+$('#timeline').html();
}
var date= new Array(selectedDate);
return date;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try turning your data into in object - with what they showed in their example

```
$('#add_image_upload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
    sequentialUploads: true,
    formData : {name:'thedate',value:getDate}
});
```

Then to add more params

```
           //name of param  // value
formData : [{name:'thedate',value:getDate},{name:'thedate2',value:'seconddate'},etc..]
```

> Example:
>
> [ { name: 'a', value: 1 }, { name: 'b', value: 2 } ]

Changing `thedate` with whatever you want to name the param

Though it sounds like a simple object should work fine

```
           //name:value
formData : {thedate:getDate}
```

Comment: @eric.itzhak NP :)  Did they both work?  I had the same problem using datatables.. I kept using {key:value} when I actually need {name:key,value:value}

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `multipart` set to `false` on your form? Also, ensure the format of what you're sending back is acceptable.

Try hard-coding the following line and sending back the info:

```
new dateobject = { "date": "1/1/2012" }
```

Comment: the data is valid i have checked